# How to redirect to another link after send reponse JSON

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-restserver

I make a API Restful with codeigniter-restserverto recieve POST request from another website, the scema is after sent response json i must redirect to another website to confirm that I have received transaction_id and signature_id

my code like this

```
/ untuk menambah person menaggunakan method post
        public function notification_post(){
            //untuk menerima data
            $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

            $order_id                   = $result['order_id'];
            $transaction_id         = $result['transaction_id'];
            $signature_key          = $result['signature_key'];

            $response = $this->km->confirm_payment(
                    $order_id,
                    $transaction_id,
                    $signature_key
                );

            $this->response($response);

            //sent to v2/update
            $confirm_order = array(
                'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
                'signature_key'  => $signature_key,
            );


            //redirect ke halaman confirm
            $link = 'http://68731fea.ngrok.io/matoa-admin/transaksi/confirm';

            redirect($link, 'location');
        }
```

the problem is, how can i redirect to $link after sent $this->response($response);

[image]

Comment: You can either redirect or send a response body, but not both at the same time. Or rather, if you redirect the response body is useless, unless you're using a special purpose client.

Comment: @Peter but the scheme requires that I send a response and call the link simultaneously, any ideas?

Comment: @Peter i post a scheme

Comment: Implement the redirect in the client, with JavaScript, for instance, if the client is a browser.

Comment: are you sure you need to actually redirect the user? generlly this ACK-type responses are expected to be sent to an API endpoint rather than a web page